# Google Ads API python Libraries imported into a Lambda are not found when using Lambda Layers created with WSL

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, google-ads-api, wsl-2, aws-lambda-layers

I use windows 11 op sys and I needed to find a way to load and package Google Ads API for python into a lambda layer.  I did this successfully for Google Campaign Management 360 API for python so I wanted to use it for Google Ads.

> So I used Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) and followed the steps
> below:

1. Run wsl in your Windows comamnd prompt
2. Install the AWS CLI: Download and install the AWS CLI on Linux machine following the instructions provided by AWS.
3. Log into AWS by running *aws configure*
4. Set up a virtual environment: *python -m venv myenv*
5. Create the `Lib\site-packages` directory: *mkdir myenv\Lib\site-packages*
6. Install the Python Google Ads libraries: *pip install --target=myenv\Lib\site-packages google-ads*
7. Package the libraries: *cd myenv\Lib\site-packages*
8. Then, create the ZIP file that contains the libraries: zip -r9 layer-package.zip .
9. Publish the Lambda layer: *aws lambda publish-layer-version --layer-name my-layer --description "My Lambda layer" --compatible-runtimes python3.10 --zip-file fileb://layer-package.zip*

> So, the Google Ads API lambda layer was created. However when I
> attached the layer to my lambda and imported certain Google Ads
> library modules into the lambda I got this error when testing the
> lambda:

```
Response
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'google.ads'",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "b8e26361-4412-4c1b-ba8b-d6934ceab99f",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

> I looked into the lambda layer and discovered that I do have this
> google.ads module installed:
> [image]

> Here is the test lambda with the import module statements listed for google ads:
> [image]

> Here is the layer attached to the lambda:
> [image]

> So when I log into my AWS environment inside my WSL Unbuntu venv, am I
> not indirectly using AWS Linux when I am packaging and publishing the
> lambda layer?  Thanks